# SDL_gfx undefined reference

Tags: c, linux, sdl

I downloaded the `SDL_gfx` and did all the stuff (`./configure`, `make install`, ...), and even the make checks, but when I'm trying to use the actual function in a source code, it says :

```
undefined reference to pixelColor.
```

I included `<SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>`, and inside the `.h` file, there is

```
int pixelColor(SDL_Surface * dst, Sint16 x, Sint16 y, Uint32)
```

Do I have to use a special compilation flag for the `SDL_gfx`?

For now I use `-lSDL -lSDL_ttf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For now I use `-lSDL -lSDL_ttf`

Link against SDL_gfx too: `-lSDL_gfx`

You should probably use `pkg-config` though:

```
`pkg-config sdl SDL_ttf SDL_gfx --libs`
```

That'll spit out everything you need, library-wise:

```
-lSDL_ttf -lSDL_gfx -lSDL
```

Comment: @ZeBulont : I know this is old, but if an answer helps you solve the problem, you should set it as the answer. (You can do it by clicking check mark under the _votes_ number)